# Deleting dynamically created QHBoxLayout and QCheckBox'es

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I'd like to know the correct way of deleting a set of vectors of pointers in a table I create to contain checkboxes

[image]

In the defining class, I declare the variables as follow :

```
   class tableFramer : public QWidget
   {
    Q_OBJECT
    public : 
       explicit tableFramer(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
       ~tableFramer();

   private: 

    QVector<QHBoxLayout*> hbLayoutPtrVector;
    QVector<QWidget*> wdgPtrVector;
    QVector<QCheckBox*> cbAcceptPtrVector;
    QVector<QCheckBox*> cbRemovePtrVector;
}
```

in the implementation I create them as follow :

```
void tableFramer::makeForm()
{
:

    ui->tableWidget->clear();

    int j  = 0;
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(this->rows);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(this->cols);
    ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(false);


    for(int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
    {
        QHBoxLayout* hbLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
        QWidget* wdg(new QWidget());
        QCheckBox* applyCb(new QCheckBox(this));
        QCheckBox* removeCb(new QCheckBox(this));

        hbLayoutPtrVector.push_back(hbLayout);
        wdgPtrVector.push_back(wdg);
        cbAcceptPtrVector.push_back(applyCb);
        cbRemovePtrVector.push_back(removeCb);
    }


    for(auto itr = hbLayoutPtrVector.begin() ; itr <= hbLayoutPtrVector.end() && j < hbLayoutPtrVector.length(); itr++ , j++ )
    {
        cbAcceptPtrVector.at(j)->setText("Opt 1");cbAcceptPtrVector.at(j)->setProperty("row",j);cbAcceptPtrVector.at(j)->setProperty("column",1);
        cbRemovePtrVector.at(j)->setText("Opt 2");cbRemovePtrVector.at(j)->setProperty("row",j);cbRemovePtrVector.at(j)->setProperty("column",1);
        (*itr)->addWidget(cbAcceptPtrVector.at(j));
        (*itr)->addWidget(cbRemovePtrVector.at(j));
        (*itr)->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        wdgPtrVector.at(j)->setLayout(*itr);
        ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(j,1,wdgPtrVector.at(j));
        ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
        ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(40);
        ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
        ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(200);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(j,0,new QTableWidgetItem(this->subfolders.at(j)));

        connect(cbAcceptPtrVector.at(j),SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(checkBoxAcceptToggeled(bool)));
        connect(cbRemovePtrVector.at(j),SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(checkBoxRejectToggeled(bool)));
    }

:
}
```

To delete the dynamically created items, in the destructor I did the following but I don't think this is done right  :

```
tableFramer::~tableFramer
{
:
if ( rows != 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rows ; ++i)
        {
            
            if(hbLayoutPtrVector[i]) 
                delete hbLayoutPtrVector[i];
            if(wdgPtrVector[i]) 
                delete wdgPtrVector[i];
            if(cbAcceptPtrVector[i]) 
                delete cbAcceptPtrVector[i];
            if(cbRemovePtrVector[i]) 
                delete cbRemovePtrVector[i];
            
            for(int j=0; j < 3; ++j)  // there are 3 columns in total
            {
                delete ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
            }
        }
        hbLayoutPtrVector.clear();
        wdgPtrVector.clear();
        cbAcceptPtrVector.clear();
        cbRemovePtrVector.clear();
    }
    rows = 0;
:
}
```

Comment: Meaning there are additional code there.....didn't want to clutter with non relevant code

Comment: Ah. Dangerous thing to do around here. If you don't know what the problem is, how can you be sure what is and isn't relevant?

Comment: tableFramer should inherit from QWidget and flow the parenting hierarchy and then you won't need to delete a thing.

Comment: Might be a bit more effective to aggregate the vectors into a single vector of a structure. Also look into `std::unique_ptr`. A vector full of those bad boys makes the cleanup look like `hbLayoutPtrVector.clear();wdgPtrVector.clear(); cbAcceptPtrVector.clear(); cbRemovePtrVector.clear();` because they're self-managing.

Comment: @asmmo  It actually does.....I just didn't show it.  I'll update the above code.  So are you saying, I do not need to delete those the pointer content in the vectors ???

Comment: It doesn't. see `new QHBoxLayout()` where is the parent here

Comment: @asmmo  Do I need to write  :  QHBoxLayout* hbLayout(new QHBoxLayout(this));
        QWidget* wdg(new QWidget(this));

Comment: Manual deletion of Qt layouts and widgets is not a good idea. I think, you should read this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html to understand the concept.